# How to always make a print of 4 figures in C

Tags: c, printf, figures

I am working on a project for university. One of the small things that make me lose points is that my answer is correct but it doesn't have four figure number.

For example say I print my answer which is `17` and on other test files it could change to 6. Is there a way I can ensure that it would always print either

0017 -> testfile_1 
0006 -> testfile_2 
0123 -> testfile_3

so it always has four digits no matter what the solution is? I made lots of test cases to check if the value is a single number or multiple to work it out but is there a simple way to do this so it automatically adds the zeros?

Comment: Doesn't `printf( "%04d", integerResult);` work?

Comment: Read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
printf( "%04d", myValue);
```

`04` will make sure that your `myValue` will always have, at least, 4 digits.

Comment: ...at least 4 digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify how many numbers printf should print, like so:

```
printf("%04d",someint);
```

Read more [here](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)